# How do I find the number for a custom binary rule?

Tags: python, binary, binary-data

As you can see below, just finding the number for this new kind of binary code requires a new method. I could count them, one by one, but it still goes over my head how to implement this correctly.

---

Take this binary code ex.

1100

and detect the number it is using the below method:

0011 - #1

0101 - #2

0110 - #3

1001 - #4

1010 - #5

1100 - #6

therefore 1100 is '6'

we then make a new code that is 6 but it has less 1s (and therefore has more 0s)! User defines how many less 1s. In this example it is 1 less 1s. So we can find it by:

000001

000010

000100

001000

010000

100000

therefore 100000 is '6'

Also, the code should work for the reverse, to make 100000 into 1100 by user defining to take away 2 0s and the code then adds 1s until it works. (All the user must do is change the 1 to 0 in the code to reverse code functionality. No extra code needed.)

The end of the code will need padding sometimes ex. all 1s ex. 1100-1111.

Answer (score 0):

The description of the "binary rules" doesn't make any sense to me, but in the first rule if you just ignore the last digit then it's a straightforward binary representation of numbers.  In the second rule it looks like it's just a function of shifting the digit to the left, which is the same as exponentiating by 2 (which you can undo with the `log2` function):

```
% cat rules.py 
import math

bin1 = 0b1100
bin2 = 0b100000
print(bin1>>1)
print(math.log2(bin2)+1)

% python rules.py 
6
6.0
```